# Lexicon for the word "pedophile"

Tags: words, nuances

I would like a list of words commonly used by Japanese to refer to pedophiles. Please indicate how common the word is (maybe sort your list this way), how derogatory it is, and in what context it is used. Medical jargon doesn't interest me unless it is used by the average man.

I know ロリコン which originally wasn't limited to manga and anime but became widespread through these media during the 80'. It is derogatory but can be used to jest. Is it still used as of today for pedophiles outside of otaku circles or does it refers mainly to them now (knowing the distinction between fiction and reality)? Is it the most used word for pedophiles or is there more common words, like maybe 小児性愛者 or 小児愛者?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **幼女趣味/幼女好き**: 幼女 refers to small girls (around 3 to 10). It's a fairly neutral word, but also used in the context of pedophilia exactly because of its neutrality.
- **ロリコン**: (From "Lolita complex") A common word that refers to a male person who likes small girls. Basically it's a derogatory word, but it's not a harsh discriminatory term, either. I have a few friends who openly call themselves ロリコン, and no one is worried about that. (Many of them married an adult woman, FWIW) Note that it does not usually refer to a certain "genre" by itself (the genre is called ロリ系, for example). Also note that this word is used more loosely when real girls are involved; for example a 23-yo male dating an 18-yo girl may be called a ロリコン by his friends, and adult idol fans are occasionally accused of being ロリコン.
- **ロリ**: Short for ロリコン. May also refer to small girls themselves (cf. [ロリババア](https://dic.pixiv.net/a/%E3%83%AD%E3%83%AA%E3%83%90%E3%83%90%E3%82%A2)). (BTW, It's also short for ロリータ, which refers to something [totally different](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lolita_fashion) today.)
- **ショタコン**: (From "[Shotaro](https://tetsujin28.fandom.com/wiki/Shotaro_Kaneda) complex") A female person who likes small boys.
- **ショタ**: Short for ショタコン, but also refers to small boys themselves.
- **ロリショタ**: Gender-neutral version used mainly by otaku. Sometimes refers to "small boys and girls" or "gender-neutral-looking small children", too.
- **ペド**: Short for "pedophilia". I heard it several times in the last 20 years or so, but I don't think it has been widely accepted.
- **小児性愛者**: Medical jargon. Sounds much more serious and pathological than the others.

Except for 小児性愛者 and ロリコン, I don't know the words for pedophile "outside of otaku circles". That's beyond my knowledge.

Comment: Yeah, I can't accept your answer because most of that is terminology used by otaku I am quite aware of. I wanted to know about non otaku people, what they are using when they talk about such issues in their everyday life. Stuff like lolibabaa are clearly fetishes. Do your friends are openly admitting to like 8-14 yo lolis in public without backlash or is just about younger girls in general, or are they saying that "openly" inside the otaku community, and/or are they referring to fictional lolis only?

Comment: @Some_user By "outside of otaku", I was thinking you were expecting argot used by those involved in illegal child porn... Ordinary people just use ロリコン (and sometimes 小児性愛者 when gender-neutrality or academic overtone is important).  When non-otaku people openly admit being a ロリコン, that may just mean they like 年下/妹/童顔-type girls.

Comment: I knew this question could be bring some discomfort but no, no, no, I am not trying to find Japanese CP. I pretty much want to know the linguistic place of lolicon with ordinary people. Are they still using lolicon when crimes are being involved (child abuse) or are they switching to something else?

Comment: @Some_user I think naruto has answered your question as well as it can be answered with regards to the Japanese language. There are cultural differences here that make this complicated. "what are they using to talk about such issues in their everyday life?" - they aren't, for the most part. As an American who lived in Japan, I think the word with (severe/negative) connotations closest to "pedophile" is 小児性愛者, but it's not an everyday word because pedophilia as a serious societal problem is not an everyday topic the way it is in the US and some other western countries.

Comment: @Some_user On TV, ロリコン is used to describe problematic/criminal ones, just as オタク is sometimes used to describe certain type of criminals. But as Mindful said, this may not be a kind of topic "ordinary" people are concerned in everyday life.

Comment: @naruto, ok, thank you for that precision, that's what I wanted to know. I am marking your answer as accepted even if I consider the real answer to be in the comments.

Comment: @naruto among anime fans/people in general, does lolicon refer to attraction to characters in anime who look/act like adults but said to be younger/in HS